Can solve a certain integral in Mathematica but don't know how to show it rigorously.
I have the definite integral:
$$ \int_0^T \exp^{\sigma}(\cos(t-\varphi)-1) \mathrm{d}t $$
Assuming that $\sigma > 0$
Now Mathematica says that when $T = 2\pi k, k \in \mathbb{N}$ this can be expressed as:
$$T \cdot \exp(-\sigma) \cdot  I_0(\sigma)$$
Where $I$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.
This does seem to work numerically. But how can it be shown? And how does it generalize to other $T$ when it needs to depend on $\varphi$?
I think this should be related to how the CDF of von Mises distribution is determined, but it's not exactly the same.

What does $\exp^\sigma$ mean to you?

I mean $(\exp(...))^{\sigma}$.

$\exp^\sigma(y)=\exp(\sigma y).$

But it seems unlikely as written to be correct, unless $T$ is known to be,an integer multiple of $2\pi.$ In particular, the fact that Mathematica gave an answer that does not depend on $\phi.$

Please give the exact Mathematica expression you used for the integral. Also the numerical work you used. This is so that we can replicate your results.

The result is exact if $T=2k\pi$

Yes, it works for $T = 2\pi k$ only, I edited the post. I am interested in general $T \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Mathematica expression is T=60*Pi; Integrate[Exp[Cos[t-phi]-1]^sigma, {t, 0, T}]

$$\exp^{\sigma}(\cos(t-\phi)-1)=e^{-\sigma}\,\exp\big(\sigma  \cos (t-\phi ) \big)$$ The only solution I can see is to write
$$\exp\big(\sigma  \cos (t-\phi ) \big)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\sigma^n} {n!}\cos ^n(t-\phi )$$ and then to work
$$I_n=\int_0^T \cos ^n(t-\phi )\,dt$$
These are given in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function since
$$\int \cos^n(z)\,dz=-\frac{\sin (z) \,\cos ^{n+1}(z)}{(n+1) \sqrt{\sin
   ^2(z)}}\,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+3}
   {2};\cos ^2(z)\right)$$
I do not think that we could expect any closed form even using special functions.
Edit
If we look at the values of the integral, using
$$U(n)=\sin (n (T-\phi ))+\sin (n \phi )$$, we have for the even values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_n \\
 0 & T \\
 2 & \frac{T}{2}+\frac{U(2)}{4} \\
 4 & \frac{3 T}{8}+\frac{U(2)}{4}+\frac{U(4)}{32}
   \\
 6 & \frac{5 T}{16}+\frac{15 U(2)}{64}+\frac{3
   U(4)}{64}+\frac{U(6)}{192} \\
 8 & \frac{35 T}{128}+\frac{7 U(2)}{32}+\frac{7
   U(4)}{128}+\frac{U(6)}{96}+\frac{U(8)}{1024} \\
 10 & \frac{63 T}{256}+\frac{105 U(2)}{512}+\frac{15
   U(4)}{256}+\frac{15 U(6)}{1024}+\frac{5
   U(8)}{2048}+\frac{U(10)}{5120}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and for the odd values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_n \\
 1 & U(1) \\
 3 &\frac{3 U(1)}{4}+\frac{U(3)}{12} \\
 5 & \frac{5 U(1)}{8}+\frac{5U(3)}{48}+\frac{U(5)}{80} \\
 7 & \frac{35 U(1)}{64}+\frac{7 U(3)}{64}+\frac{7U(5)}{320}
+\frac{U(7)}{448} \\
 9 & \frac{63 U(1)}{128}+\frac{7 U(3)}{64}+\frac{9U(5)}{320}
+\frac{9U(7)}{1792}+\frac{U(9)}{2304} \\
11 &\frac{231 U(1)}{512}+\frac{55 U(3)}{512}+\frac{33U(5)}{1024}
+\frac{55 U(7)}{7168}+\frac{11U(9)}{9216}+\frac{U(11)}{11264}
\end{array}
\right)$$
It would be a good idea to look at $OEIS$ to find sequences.

Why is there $\sqrt{\sin^2(z)}$ in the denominator? Is that just $|\sin(z)|$?

@user1747134. Have a look at the edit.
